# Restrict what type of barcode ZXing will detect

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, zxing

I am using `ZXingObjC` to scan from a live camera feed in my iOS `Swift` app (using [this sample code](https://github.com/thongbin/ZxingDemo-Swift/blob/master/ZxingDemo-Swift/TBCaptureViewController.swift)). I would like to restrict the available barcode types that ZXing will look for, or return for that matter. Specifically, I'd like it to ignore anything but **Aztec** codes. Currently it always detects my demo code as UPCE, and I'm looking to prevent that.

It seems there is a way to do this via *Intents* on Android, but I'm not sure how to do this for iOS/ZXingObjC. Can someone point me in the right direction?
Can I supply a filter to the
`func captureResult(capture: ZXCapture, result: ZXResult, barcodeFormat: String?)` or do I have to change the way `ZXCapture` is called?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the `ZXDecodeHints` class, you have these methods to add or remove the formats recognised by the scanner.

```
- (void)addPossibleFormat:(ZXBarcodeFormat)format;
- (BOOL)containsFormat:(ZXBarcodeFormat)format;
- (int)numberOfPossibleFormats;
- (void)removePossibleFormat:(ZXBarcodeFormat)format;
```

So that you can remove the format you don't want:

```
  [hints removePossibleFormat:kBarcodeFormatQRCode]
```

Here are the list of formats used by the lib:

```
typedef enum {
  /** Aztec 2D barcode format. */
  kBarcodeFormatAztec,

  /** CODABAR 1D format. */
  kBarcodeFormatCodabar,

  /** Code 39 1D format. */
  kBarcodeFormatCode39,

  /** Code 93 1D format. */
  kBarcodeFormatCode93,

  /** Code 128 1D format. */
  kBarcodeFormatCode128,

  /** Data Matrix 2D barcode format. */
  kBarcodeFormatDataMatrix,

  /** EAN-8 1D format. */
  kBarcodeFormatEan8,

  /** EAN-13 1D format. */
  kBarcodeFormatEan13,

  /** ITF (Interleaved Two of Five) 1D format. */
  kBarcodeFormatITF,

  /** MaxiCode 2D barcode format. */
  kBarcodeFormatMaxiCode,

  /** PDF417 format. */
  kBarcodeFormatPDF417,

  /** QR Code 2D barcode format. */
  kBarcodeFormatQRCode,

  /** RSS 14 */
  kBarcodeFormatRSS14,

  /** RSS EXPANDED */
  kBarcodeFormatRSSExpanded,

  /** UPC-A 1D format. */
  kBarcodeFormatUPCA,

  /** UPC-E 1D format. */
  kBarcodeFormatUPCE,

  /** UPC/EAN extension format. Not a stand-alone format. */
  kBarcodeFormatUPCEANExtension
} ZXBarcodeFormat;
```

Also in the `ZXMultiFormatReader` class, you should remove the objects in the array readers which stores the different formats.

```
[self.readers addObject:[[ZXQRCodeReader alloc] init]];
[self.readers addObject:[[ZXDataMatrixReader alloc] init]];
[self.readers addObject:[[ZXAztecReader alloc] init]];
[self.readers addObject:[[ZXPDF417Reader alloc] init]];
[self.readers addObject:[[ZXMaxiCodeReader alloc] init]];
```

you should remove these line calls which you don't want.

Comment: Thanks! This sounds great, but I could not get it to work. I even changed the loop that adds all the formats so it adds only one (Aztec) `[result addPossibleFormat:[@0 intValue]];` but my app still reports UPCE as the detected barcode type. Weird.